# How to save utc from the manually selected datetime in azure web app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, azure, timezone, datetimepicker

In my project i saving the selected datetime(in UTC) from my datepicker.It saves the utc datetime only while application running in local.After deploying to azure it saves the selected datetime from datepicker irrespective of utc.

**Update :**

```
string selecteddate = "12/04/2016 05:30:15";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(selecteddate).ToUniversalTime();
```

this code saves utc datetime in db in localhost,But it not working in azure

Comment: can we have any code snippet about how you're saving the date?

Comment: string selecteddate = "12/04/2016 05:30:15";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(selecteddate).ToUniversalTime(); this code saves **utc datetime** in db in localhost,But it not working in azure

Comment: Do you have any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

The `DateTime` instance you create with `Convert.ToDateTime(selecteddate)` will have `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  Because of this, when you then call `ToUniversalTime`, it is making the assumption that the source value is in the local time zone of the computer where the code is running.

On Azure, that time zone is *already* UTC, so while the `.Kind` will change to `DateTimeKind.Utc`, the value will stay the same.

If you intended it to be converted from a particular time zone, then use `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc` instead, passing a specific `TimeZoneInfo` value for the time zone you care about.

In general, don't rely on the local time zone setting in a web app, as the time zone could be different depending on where you deploy.  Avoid `ToUniversalTime` and `ToLocalTime`, as well as `DateTime.Now` and other functions that depend on the local machine's time zone setting.